# Unable to Compile JSP Java class in AppEngine

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine

I was creating a quiz application in java to host on Google App Engine. However when I am trying to Deploy it, it gives an error that unable to compile JSP java Class. Even if I try to upload a blank JSP. On local server, everything works fine.
The error is shown below.

### Console Error on Eclipse:

> ------------ Deploying frontend ------------
>
> Preparing to deploy:
>     Created staging directory at:
>   '/var/folders/2y/f99pqznd5m3g21gbjl7rgjc40000gn/T/appcfg966104224651839827.tmp'
>
> Scanning for jsp files.
>     Compiling jsp files.
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to
>   compile the generated JSP java files. Sep 02, 2015 6:35:38 PM
>   org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile INFO: Built File: /index.jsp
>
> Debugging information may be found in
>   /private/var/folders/2y/f99pqznd5m3g21gbjl7rgjc40000gn/T/appengine-deploy2339970973769784997.log

I have already tried to find solution regarding this. However no success till now.
The JSP file is shown below. Its not doing anything, still I am getting the error:

### index.jsp

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TechnoQuiz | Registration</title>
<meta
 content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no'
 name='viewport'>

<link href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
 type="text/css" />
<link
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
 type="text/css" />

</head>
<body class="register-page"
 style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('dist/img/carbon_pattern.png');">
 <div class="register-box">

  <div class="register-box-body">
   <div class="register-logo">
    <a><b>ZapQuiz</b>.Space</a>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <p class="login-box-msg">Please fill in the details below</p>

   <form name="regform">

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
     <input name="fullname" type="text" class="form-control"
      placeholder="Full name" /> <span
      class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
     <p id="err1" class="text-red hidden">Can't be Empty</p>

    </div>
    <div id="email" class="form-group has-feedback">
     <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"
      required /> <span
      class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
     <p id="err2" class="text-red hidden">Can't be Empty</p>

    </div>

    <div id="phone" class="form-group has-feedback">
     <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" /> <span
      class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback"></span>
     <p id="err3" class="text-red hidden">Can't be Empty</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Register</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <p class="login-box-msg">
     Powered by <strong>Xibeat Technologies</strong>
    </p>

   </form>

  </div>

 </div>



 <script src="../../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

I tried to resolve the issue by going through the generated Java class in the Temp Directory. However, I don't see anything wrong.

### Generated JAVA class by AppEngine in the Temp Directory

```html
package org.apache.jsp;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;

public final class index_jsp extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
    implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent {

  private static final JspFactory _jspxFactory = JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();

  private static java.util.List _jspx_dependants;

  private javax.el.ExpressionFactory _el_expressionfactory;
  private org.apache.AnnotationProcessor _jsp_annotationprocessor;

  public Object getDependants() {
    return _jspx_dependants;
  }

  public void _jspInit() {
    _el_expressionfactory = _jspxFactory.getJspApplicationContext(getServletConfig().getServletContext()).getExpressionFactory();
    _jsp_annotationprocessor = (org.apache.AnnotationProcessor) getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute(org.apache.AnnotationProcessor.class.getName());
  }

  public void _jspDestroy() {
  }

  public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

    PageContext pageContext = null;
    HttpSession session = null;
    ServletContext application = null;
    ServletConfig config = null;
    JspWriter out = null;
    Object page = this;
    JspWriter _jspx_out = null;
    PageContext _jspx_page_context = null;


    try {
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      pageContext = _jspxFactory.getPageContext(this, request, response,
         null, true, 8192, true);
      _jspx_page_context = pageContext;
      application = pageContext.getServletContext();
      config = pageContext.getServletConfig();
      session = pageContext.getSession();
      out = pageContext.getOut();
      _jspx_out = out;

      out.write("<html>\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n<title>TechnoQuiz | Registration</title>\n<meta\n\tcontent='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no'\n\tname='viewport'>\n\n<link href=\"../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"\n\ttype=\"text/css\" />\n<link\n\thref=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css\"\n\trel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n<link href=\"../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"\n\ttype=\"text/css\" />\n\n</head>\n<body class=\"register-page\"\n\tstyle=\"background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('dist/img/carbon_pattern.png');\">\n\t<div class=\"register-box\">\n\n\t\t<div class=\"register-box-body\">\n\t\t\t<div class=\"register-logo\">\n\t\t\t\t<a><b>ZapQuiz</b>.Space</a>\n\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t<hr>\n\t\t\t<p class=\"login-box-msg\">Please fill in the details below</p>\n\n\t\t\t<form name=\"regform\">\n\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"form-group has-feedback\">\n\t\t\t\t\t<input name=\"fullname\" type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\"\n\t\t\t\t\t\tplaceholder=\"Full name\" /> <span\n\t\t\t\t\t\tclass=\"glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback\"></span>\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t\t\t<p id=\"err1\" class=\"text-red hidden\">Can't be Empty</p>\n\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t<div id=\"email\" class=\"form-group has-feedback\">\n\t\t\t\t\t<input type=\"email\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Email\"\n\t\t\t\t\t\trequired /> <span\n\t\t\t\t\t\tclass=\"glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback\"></span>\n\t\t\t\t\t<p id=\"err2\" class=\"text-red hidden\">Can't be Empty</p>\n\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n\n\t\t\t\t<div id=\"phone\" class=\"form-group has-feedback\">\n\t\t\t\t\t<input type=\"tel\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Phone\" /> <span\n\t\t\t\t\t\tclass=\"glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback\"></span>\n\t\t\t\t\t<p id=\"err3\" class=\"text-red hidden\">Can't be Empty</p>\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"row\">\n\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"col-xs-12\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat\">Register</button>\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t<hr>\n\t\t\t\t<p class=\"login-box-msg\">\n\t\t\t\t\tPowered by <strong>Xibeat Technologies</strong>\n\t\t\t\t</p>\n\n\t\t\t</form>\n\n\t\t</div>\n\n\t</div>\n\n\n\n\t<script src=\"../../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js\"></script>\n\t<script src=\"../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js\"\n");
      out.write("\t\ttype=\"text/javascript\"></script>\n\n\n\n</body>\n</html>");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      if (!(t instanceof SkipPageException)){
        out = _jspx_out;
        if (out != null && out.getBufferSize() != 0)
          try { out.clearBuffer(); } catch (java.io.IOException e) {}
        if (_jspx_page_context != null) _jspx_page_context.handlePageException(t);
      }
    } finally {
      _jspxFactory.releasePageContext(_jspx_page_context);
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, Here is the AppEngine-web.xml File and Web.xml file. In case it may come handy.

### appengine-web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>zapquiz-1054</application>
  <version>1</version>

  <!--
    Allows App Engine to send multiple requests to one instance in parallel:
  -->
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>      
</appengine-web-app>
```

### web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  
    
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>   
</web-app>
```

Thanks and Regards,
Prasun

### UPDATE: Log file is shown below

> Unable to update:
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to
>   compile the generated JSP java files.     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJavaFiles(Application.java:854)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:815)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:629)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:509)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:158)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

Comment: is there more information in the error log file `/private/var/folders/2y/f99pqznd5m3g21gbjl7rgjc40000gn/T/appengine-deploy2339970973769784997.log`

Comment: @wero I updated the question with the log file .... the log file don't give any info which I could find helpful in debugging.

Comment: are you usign the JDK to compile or just JRE?

Comment: I configured my eclipse to use a jdk 7.64 by mentioning it in the eclipse.ini file on the my mac